Can a noexcept C++ function be passed as pointer-to-function to an argument for a function with C linkage?
Imagine the following situation where I have a noexcept C++ free function that is passed as function pointer to another function with C linkage:
extern "C" {
   void some_fun(void(*)());
}

void my_fun() noexcept { /* do stuff */; }

int main()
{
   some_fun(my_fun);
}

Is that correct and/or allowed? What happens in this case? What are the semantics here considering that since C++17 noexcept belongs to the type of a function?
In addition, and to my surprise, this even compiles (with both gcc and clang):
extern "C" {
   void some_fun(void(*)() noexcept);
}

void my_fun() noexcept { /* do stuff */; }

int main()
{
   some_fun(my_fun);
}

Does it even make sense that a function pointer in the signature of a C function allows the qualifier noexcept in it?

noexcept functions can "decay" to function pointers that lack this promise.  Your code is well-defined.  (I'm not posting as an answer so someone can cite an authority)

@DrewDormann What about the noexcept in the declaration of the C function?

Why do you think extern "C" makes it a "C function" all of a sudden? All it does is tell the compiler to disable name mangling.

@ABu You can assign a noexcept function to a pointer that lacks the noexcept guarantee.  You can not assign a function that lacks noexcept to a noexcept function pointer.

If you want to see an error, try removing noexcept from my_fun in your second code block, keeping the noexcept in the parameter to some_fun. (Note that you can remove the extern "C" and still get the error.)

@Botje you should avoid doing that kind of patronizing or condescending questions or whatever their name. I knew that extern "C" disables name mangling but didn't expect that to be literally it.

Programming is hard enough, no need to ascribe magic behavior to keywords. They are what they are.


Is that correct and/or allowed? What happens in this case? What are the semantics here considering that since C++17 noexcept belongs to the type of a function?

It is correct and allowed. What happens is that there is an implicit conversion sequence from void(*)() noexcept to void(*)() (but not the other way around). This conversion will convert the function pointer to the expected type without noexcept. The function can be called through the pointer without noexcept without any restrictions.

In addition, and to my surprise, this even compiles (with both gcc and clang):

There is no requirement that types used in a function declaration with "C" linkage must be C types. From the point of view of C++ there is no difference to normal behavior, except that the name of the function ignores namespaces and can't be overloaded (i.e. from the typical implementation point-of-view name mangling is disable).
However, what such a declaration means for actual interop with C code, is implementation-defined. Of course you wouldn't be able to declare or define the function with the same signature in C. If you changed the signature for the C part of the program, you should really be sure about the specific way in which your compiler compiles the code to make sure that there is well-defined behavior.

As the other answer by @Artyer points out, according to the standard, the language linkage of a function is part of its type and the function parameter in the function declared with "C" linkage inherits this language linkage. my_fun is not a function with "C" linkage and therefore can't be passed as a pointer to a function with "C" linkage. I suppose this is intended to allow different calling conventions between C and C++. In all cases I am aware of compilers ignore this part of the standard and consider the language linkage not part of the type.

So to implement in C an extern "C" function receiving, let's say, an std::string as parameter, I guess the C implementation of that function should take into considerations ABI conventions and such to know if the parameter is in registers or the stack and all these of things, and do it manually, am I right?

@ABu I guess so, but I am not sure that it would typically be possible to write a "compatible" C declaration at all. Also, if you e.g. use LTO across the C and C++ translation units, I have no idea what requirements the compiler imposes. I would expect it to not be happy with mismatching declaration (which in LTO mode can be diagnosed).

@ABu Just for one impossibility to make it compatible with C: In some ABIs the callee is responsible for calling destructors of (by-value) parameters with non-trivial destructor. You won't be able to do that properly in C code, even if you get the calling convention to match.

@user17732522 there probably wouldn't be a portable way .Essentially we have to pass object as opaque.. pointers to void? And then C code should call something external with these to perform operations. I saw it done, actually, quite a few widely-used industrial API are based on that, hiding pointers to complex objects under macro definitions of void* :P

This is not allowed in standard C++. See also: Is `extern "C"` a part of the type of a function?, std::qsort. The parameter to some_fun is declared as a "pointer to a C function", and there is no standard conversion from "pointer to a C++ function" to "pointer to C function".
C functions are allowed to be noexcept. For example, extern "C" void my_fun() noexcept { /* do stuff */; } would be a C function, and you can pass a pointer to it to some_fun. (There is an implicit function conversion to remove the noexcept)
GCC, Clang and MSVC at least do not distinguish between C and C++ functions, not even recording it as part of the type, allowing this to compile.
I've found a single example of a compiler not accepting this: How do you declare an extern "C" function pointer

Do you know what compiler that is that actually considers the language linkage part of the function type? I have never seen that actually implemented conforming to the standard.

@user17732522 Following the link and doing a little searching, it looks like it's from an HP system.

@user17732522 actualy i think it never can fully conform to standard unless we'll create some thick compatibility layer between C and C++ space or "C" space in reality doesn't exist at all (like in MSVC in past, there was only "Microsoft C++" and "pascal call")
